# How I can subset a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have the following two lists:

```
list_dummy = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['d', 'a', 'c'] ]
must_have = ['a', 'b']
```

I want to "subset" the first list, meaning that I only want to keep the lists within `list_dummy` that have the elements `a` and `b`

The expected result should be:

```
list_sub = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd']]
```

How I can do this in python and please also consider that the `list_dummy` might be large so some scalable solution would be appreciated.

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert them to sets and then check if their intersection is same as the must_have set.

```
list_dummy = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['d', 'a', 'c'] ]
must_have = ['a', 'b']
must_have_set = set(must_have)
print([x for x in list_dummy if set(x) & must_have_set == must_have_set])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use issubset

```
list_dummy = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['d', 'a', 'c']]
must_have = ['a', 'b']
list_sub = [i for i in list_dummy if set(must_have).issubset(i)]
print(list_sub)
```